# ILM using Logstash Elasticsearch output plugin doesn't work

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-x-pack

I'm trying to implement ILM for an index to properly use hardware, using the Elasticsearch output plugin. Looks like I misunderstand how Logstash manages ILM.

I have ELK stack version 7.1.0 in docker. X-Pack is activated by trial license.

The index template is managed by Logstash Elasticsearch output plugin and the index lifecycle policy was created using Kibana.

Here is the output section of Logstash pipeline:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://eshost:9200"]
        user => "logstash_writer"
        password => "pass"
        template => "/usr/share/logstash/es_templates/ilm-template.json"
        template_name => "ilm-template"
        template_overwrite => true
        ilm_enabled => true
        ilm_rollover_alias => "ilm-index"
        ilm_pattern => "000001"
        ilm_policy => "base-policy"
    }
}
```

User `logstash_writer` has default role `logstash_writer` with permissions for ILM management.

Elasticsearch index template `ilm-template.json`:

```
{
  "settings" : {
    "index.number_of_replicas" : "1",
    "index.number_of_shards" : "1",
    "index.refresh_interval" : "5s"
  }
}
```

Elasticsearch index template `_template/ilm-template` that was actually created by Logstash:

```
{
  "ilm-template" : {
    "order" : 0,
    "index_patterns" : [
      "ilm-index-*"
    ],
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "lifecycle" : {
          "name" : "base-policy",
          "rollover_alias" : "ilm-index"
        },
        "refresh_interval" : "5s",
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1"
      }
    },
    "mappings" : { },
    "aliases" : { }
  }
}
```

Policy `base-policy` created using Kibana:

```
{
    "policy": {
        "phases": {
            "hot": {
                "min_age": "0ms",
                "actions": {
                    "rollover": {
                        "max_size": "100mb",
                        "max_docs": 100000
                    },
                    "set_priority": {
                        "priority": 100
                    }
                }
            },
            "delete": {
                "min_age": "2d",
                "actions": {
                    "delete": {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the set of indices `ilm-index-*`, but only `ilm-index-000001` is created and constantly growing, despite the limitations of `base-policy`. So I only see in Kibana one index (`ilm-index-000001`) associated with `base-policy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided configuration is correct. The problem is in interpretation of `max_size` and `max_docs` parameters when they have small value. Elasticsearch doesn't rollover indices when it's `pri.store.size` and `docs.count` become larger than set in `max_size` and `max_docs`.